# Wordpress- Echo PHP into Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've run into a little bit of a snag with shortcodes.  I want it to take the variable and put it in place for the text that should usually go there, but instead of working it just doesn't load it up, even though I've tested it with the echo to see if it's putting anything out and it is.

```
<?php 
    $artistslug = the_field('artist_cat_slug');
    echo $artistslug;    // Here for test reasons
    echo do_shortcode('[product_category category="'.$artistslug.'"]');
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `the_field()` is not a default WordPress function - is this from a plugin?

Comment: Sorry yeah i should clarify this is with Advanced Custom Fields plugin, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, `the_field()` **displays** the value. The plugin you are using might have a corresponding function to **return** the value instead, for e.g. `get_the_field()`. Use that instead.

**Edit after [clarification in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858794/wordpress-echo-php-into-shortcode/21858866#comment33091124_21858794)**

From the [documentation for `the_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/) (*emphasis* mine):

> *Displays* the value of the specified field. (this is the same as `echo get_field($field_name)`)

Exactly. Use [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/) instead.

Comment: `Call to undefined function get_the_field() in /var/sites/i/inlandclothing.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/inlandclothing/page-artist.php on line 27`

I get this when i put it as get_the_field

Comment: @MatthewArtiman: See the spelling. It's `get_field()` not `get_the_field()`.